# how do I upload data to fusion tables through the API?

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

Is there a way to do this with the public key? or do I need OAUTH? I am just trying to create a table, upload rows and make it public, is this possible without having to use a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

- **Is there a way to do this with the public key:** No
- **do I need OAUTH:** yes, all these operations require authorization via OAuth2
- **is this possible without having to use a web browser:** the authorization via OAuth2 also includes a authorization-window where the user has to confirm the authorization, so you'll need a browser

Additionally: setting  the permissions is not possible via the FusionTablesAPI(see https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=74 , you'll also find  a workaround there)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a service account. It will allow you to do all of the fusion table operations and you can use the drive api to change the permissions on the fusion table.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#service-accounts